# Page not found in WordPress Pagination

Tags: wordpress

On [this](http://elan.grappetite.com/nieuws) page, if you click on pagination, it shows 404 not found. Here is what I have done,
From Functions.php,

```
<?php

/*------------------------------------*\

    Custom Post Types

\*------------------------------------*/



// Create 1 Custom Post type for a Demo, called HTML5-Blank

function create_post_type_html5()

{

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');

    register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type

        array(

        'labels' => array(

            'name' => __('News', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit

            'singular_name' => __('News', 'html5blank'),

            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),

            'add_new_item' => __('News', 'html5blank'),

            'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),

            'edit_item' => __('Edit HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),

            'new_item' => __('New News', 'html5blank'),

            'view' => __('View News', 'html5blank'),

            'view_item' => __('View  News', 'html5blank'),

            'search_items' => __('Search News', 'html5blank'),

            'not_found' => __('No News found', 'html5blank'),

            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No News found in Trash', 'html5blank')

        ),

        'public' => true,

        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages

        'has_archive' => true,

        'supports' => array(

            'title',

            'editor',

            'excerpt',

            'thumbnail'

        ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports

        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export

        'taxonomies' => array(

            'post_tag',

            'category'

        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support

    ));

}



/*------------------------------------*\

    ShortCode Functions

\*------------------------------------*/



// Shortcode Demo with Nested Capability

function html5_shortcode_demo($atts, $content = null)

{

    return '<div class="shortcode-demo">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>'; // do_shortcode allows for nested Shortcodes

}



// Shortcode Demo with simple <h2> tag

function html5_shortcode_demo_2($atts, $content = null) // Demo Heading H2 shortcode, allows for nesting within above element. Fully expandable.

{

    return '<h2>' . $content . '</h2>';

}

function wpse120407_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // Test for category archive index

    // and ensure that the query is the main query

    // and not a secondary query (such as a nav menu

    // or recent posts widget output, etc.

    if ( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Modify posts per page

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );

    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse120407_pre_get_posts' );

function my_post_count_queries( $query ) {

  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

       $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);

  }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_count_queries' );

?>
```

pagination code after the loop,

```
    <ul class="pager">

    <?php

    global $wp_query;



    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $translated = __( '', 'mytextdomain' ); // Supply translatable string



    echo paginate_links( array(

        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

        'format' => '?paged=%#%',

        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,

        'before_page_number' => '<li class=""><span>',

        'after_page_number'  => '</span> </li>'

    ) );

    ?>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Write this above while loop**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$post_query = query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'cover', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));



?>
```

**At bottom**

```
global $wp_query;



 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

  echo paginate_links( array(
       'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
       'format' => '?paged=%#%',
       'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
       'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
   ) );

  ?>
```

Comment: Where is the area for custom post type in your code?

Comment: 'post_type'      => 'cover', // You can add a custom post type if you like

Comment: I added this code. It doesn;t seem  to be different from my code.

Comment: you need to customize according to your requiremnet

Answer (score 0):

```
global $paged;

if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

$args = array (
'paged'  => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => '3',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$Qvar = new WP_Query( $args );
..................
.......

<?php if ($Qvar->max_num_pages > 1) { ?>
        <div class="pager-prev">
            <?php
                if (!empty(get_previous_posts_link( ' Previous' ))) {
                    echo '<span></span>'.get_previous_posts_link( ' Previous' );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="pager-next">
            <?php
                if (!empty(get_next_posts_link( 'Next', $Qvar->max_num_pages ))) {
                    echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next', $Qvar->max_num_pages ).'<span></span>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```